# 3D Acceleration Not working with Virtualbox Tools 5.2.6

Tags: unity, virtualbox, 3d

According to other posts I do the following...

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p  
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 5.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 17.2.4

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

So I try rerunning the autorun and add `vboxvideo` to `/etc/modules` and then shutdown and restart with 3D acceleration checked. When I do this, however, after the initial screen with ubuntu and the little dots it just gets stuck on a black page.

How do I get Ubuntu to boot with 3D acceleration installed?

**Update**

I had a request for info on my environment. I was trying to leave that as open ended as possible but here is the setup.

Host: OSX
Guest: Ubuntu
Normal Macbook so it uses the AMD drivers

**Update 2**

I have confirmed this is actually using VBOX per

```
$ /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.2.6/bin/VBoxControl 
Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions Command Line Management Interface Version 5.2.6
```

I confirmed there was a vware lib installed but it seems to be installed by the system...

```
 apt list --installed | grep vm
 ....
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:13.2.1-1build1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

I removed the package and restarted, however, I still see....

```
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
```

Comment: This question is a bit unclear... Are you running Ubuntu as a host or are you running it in Virtualbox?

Comment: Ubuntu is a guest on an OSX Host. So it is running in VirtualBox. Sorry I just assumed the commands would make it clear the Ubuntu server was a guest but I will clarify.

Comment: This seems like more of an OSX+VB problem and is therefore not really suited for **askubuntu**. Unless 3D acceleration works for you with other guests, I suggest you have a look into the [Virtual Box forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=85014) where this  problem is already being discussed or on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). Unable to flag because of the bounty.

Comment: Hi Jackie, are you really running a VirtualBox VM ? I am asking because I see "OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc." This let's me assume that you are running Ubuntu in a vmware virtual machine. Please check in case whether the vmware tools (not the VirtualBox Guest Additions) are properly installed. :)

Comment: @RobertRiedl I will confirm it works with a Windows guest if I can.

cl-netbox I have confirmed it was VirtualBox and I am installing from the VBOX CD (VBOX Ga 5.26). I double checked apt list just to make sure there wasn't something weird like an old VMware package installed, but I don't see anything.

Comment: Thanks for checking! It seems pretty odd that it would say 'VMware' anywhere, unless the graphics drivers aren't installed properly... You might want to check out this forum thread: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=79233 (It's old, but may be helpful)

Comment: Perhaps you could try: sudo apt-get autoremove --purge xserver-xorg-video-vmware

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this issue relates to OSX. @RobertRiedl looks like you may have been the closest. I installed Developer Tools and XQuartz, this gave me access to `glxinfo`. Running `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` then gave me the following...

```
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 M370X OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version string: 2.1 ATI-1.60.26
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

This leads me to believe it is using OpenGL 2.1 which isn't supported by Ubuntu for 3D accerleration EmIRight?

This is also pretty strange as their own documentation says they support 4.1 (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823)

Comment: According to this (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283434/which-opengl-version-is-correct) they only support the General version up to 2.1 and if you want to use higher you need Apple's special version. Wondering if I can compile VBox from source and get it to work, anyone?

Comment: You could certainly [try](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Build_instructions) but if you are looking for information regarding the feasibility of changing the VBox code to support 3D under OSX you might want to ask the [VirtualBox Community](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Community)

Comment: Elder, honestly I think it might be best on Ask Different don't you?

Comment: [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is an excellent suggestion as well.